# How can I fix "Could not build wheels for scikit-image" error?

Tags: python, pip, scikit-image

I am installing scikit-image , during the installation it throws wheel compilation error.

```
 Platform      :
    Architecture: x64
    Compiler    : msvc

  CPU baseline  :
    Requested   : 'min'
    Enabled     : none
    Flags       : none
    Extra checks: none

  CPU dispatch  :
    Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
    Enabled     : none
    Generated   : none
  CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[809] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\dimit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aq2rykzx\scikit-image_b1ce32750a55476abaacce9574e7b7cb\build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py    
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Full log: https://paste-bin.xyz/18767

Comment: I would suggest to download and install a [whl file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image) instead of trying to make a source compilation work. The problem is that there are no official whl files for scikit-image for python 3.10 yet. Alternatively, you could downgrade to python 3.9

Comment: As, advised, I have installed manually scikit_image-0.18.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl. Installation was successful, however when I try to import skimage, I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'

Comment: Can you confirm that you installed the whl with `C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe -m pip install` and then also ran your script with `C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe`?

Answer (score 4):

Download the appropriate file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image)

And using pip, install the file as: `pip install *.whl`

For me worked `pip install scikit_image-0.19.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl --user` in Python 3.11